# Converting List to Dict

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, dictionary

When I had a list that was in format of

```
list1 = [[James,24],[Ryan,21],[Tim,32]...etc]
```

I could use

```
dic1 =dict(list1)
```

However now lets say I have multiple values such as

```
list1 = [[James,24,Canada,Blue,Tall],[Ryan,21,U.S.,Green,Short
[Tim,32,Mexico,Yellow,Average]...etc]
```

I have no idea how to go about creating a dict so that it would show the first name as the key and the following values as the value.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use a [dict comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) and slicing :

```
>>> list1 = [['James','24','Canada','Blue','Tall'],['Ryan','21','U.S.','Green','Short']]
>>> {i[0]:i[1:] for i in list1}
{'James': ['24', 'Canada', 'Blue', 'Tall'], 'Ryan': ['21', 'U.S.', 'Green', 'Short']}
```

In python 3 you can use a more elegant way with unpacking operation :

```
>>> {i:j for i,*j in list1}
{'James': ['24', 'Canada', 'Blue', 'Tall'], 'Ryan': ['21', 'U.S.', 'Green', 'Short']}
```

Answer (score 2):

Loop through the entries of your list and add them to the dictionary:

```
for entry in list:
    dict[entry[0]]=entry[1:]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using star unpacking.
If the key does not exist, insert the key, with the empty value.
Extend doesn't require any elements. It works on an empty list.

```
s =  [['James','24','Canada','Blue','Tall'],['Ryan','21','U.S.','Green','Short']]

output = {}

for k, *v in s:
    if v:
        output.setdefault(k, []).extend(v)
    else:
        output[k] = None
       
print(output )
```

```
{'James': ['24', 'Canada', 'Blue', 'Tall'], 'Ryan': ['21', 'U.S.', 'Green', 'Short']}

[Program finished]
```